# right way to make an abstract base class which registers callback

Tags: c++, callback

I want to have a base class which has the purpose of registering it for a callback (and de-registering in destructor), the callback is a pure virtual function. Like this.

```
struct autoregister {
  autoregister() { callback_manager.register(this); }
  ~autoregister() { callback_manager.deregister(this); }
  virtual void call_me()=0;
};
```

But this seems unreliable to me, I suspect there are several race conditions in there. 1) When the callback_manager sees the pointer, the call_me is still uncallable, and it could take an arbitrary amount of time until the object finishes construction, 2) by the time deregister is called, the derived object destructor was called, so the callbacks should not be called.

One of the things I was thinking, was to check, inside callback_manager, if the pointer's call_me is valid or not, but I can't find a standard compliant way to get the address of call_me or anything. I was thinking of comparing typeid(pointer) to typeid(autoregister*) but there might be an abstract class inbetween, making this unreliable, derived : public middle {}; middle : public autoregister {};, middle's constructor can spend an hour, e.g. loading SQL or searching google, and the callback sees that it's not the base class, and thinks the callback can be invoked, and boom. Can this be done?

Q1: are there other race conditions?

Q2: how to do this right (without race conditions, undefined behavior and other errors) without asking the derived class to call register manually?

Q3: how to check if a virtual function can be called on a pointer?

Comment: Nice question. I'd always call deregister and register with an instance level mutex.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but based on your comments, it's clear this isn't even close to clear about your actual needs (and since you persist in claiming that your needs haven't been answered, even though the issues you've raised in the comments have been addressed, it seems unlikely that you've done enough research to be sure what you really even want).

Comment: @JerryCoffin please read the question, I'm clearly interested in a base class based solution first, for whatever reasons. So far the most relevant answer to my question is the single one without code, by user634175, other answers give alternatives, each with different trade-offs. But vote as you please, your prerogative. Now I'm waiting to see if something better comes along, then I'll accept whichever answer seems best.

Comment: @Martin: one of the most basic points of object oriented programming is to learn to separate the interface from the implementation. The interface specifies the behavior. The question you should be asking is how to get the desired behavior cleanly, not specify an implementation, and somehow get it to do the opposite of what it's designed to do.

Comment: @JerryCoffin what I'm asking however is "can I do it this way? If I can what are the gotchas?", If I get alternatives, good, but the reason for the question is to know if a different way is possible. All the other ways were known to me, maybe someone will show something new. Clean code and clean design seems to be a matter of opinion, I'd not call using an operator for this clean, that can be good sometimes, but IMHO having a function whose name says what it's for is better, cleaner, more expressive. You're free to disagree. But please refrain from wasting more time on these tangents. Thanks

Comment: @Martin: Trying to teach people how to design programs doesn't strike me as a waste of time, nor a tangent, but I guess if you do, that's your own problem.

Comment: @JerryCoffin teaching people isn't, but you're trying to tell me to use an random object's () operator for callbacks, without any regard to the object. That's bad advice, and instead of thinking about it, you're pushing it even harder. Are you seriously telling me you expect me to learn from this? Look at Alexey's response, "sure, you can do the same without lambdas". And the downvote and the remark about my skills is also your teaching method? You may want to tweak you style.

Comment: I clearly stated why I gave a downvote--your statements in the comments make it clear that the question, as asked, does a poor job of explaining what you really want (i.e., you've postulated requirements not even hinted at in the question). If somebody doesn't know how to use `typedef`, saying they lack understanding of even the basics of C++ isn't an insult--it's a statement of indisputable fact.

Comment: @JerryCoffin my very first comment to your question mentions typedef, what else do you question I know?

Comment: It *mentions* typedef, but seems to (completely?) misunderstand what it's for or how it's used. It was what prompted my initial question about your skill level.

Comment: @JerryCoffin please explain how the comment implies that

Comment: The "I could use a typedef, then if I want a second callback it will be `register_boom<register_bang<derived>>` " seemed to imply that you thought a typedef would significantly affect how registering a second callback would work. Rereading it and trying to be as generous as I can, I suppose *maybe* that's not what it's intended to say, but it sure seems like the obvious reading, to the point that I have to work pretty hard to interpret it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of your autoregister, since the object has not fully been constructed yet, the 'this' pointer is dangerous to pass out to the callback_manager. I would recommend a slightly different design.

```
struct callback {
  virtual void call_me() = 0;
}

struct autoregister {
  callback*const callback_;

  autoregister(callback*const _callback)
    : callback_(_callback) {
    callback_manager.register(callback_);
  }

  ~autoregister() {
    callback_manager.deregister(callback_);
  }
};
```

Q1: are there other race conditions?

Maybe. Your callback_manager must be synchronized, if multiple threads may use it. But my version of autoregister itself does not have race condition.

Q2: how to do this right (without race conditions, undefined behavior and other errors) without asking the derived class to call register manually?

My code is how I think can do this right.

Q3: how to check if a virtual function can be called on a pointer?

Not necessary in my code. But in general you could keep in the class a flag which is set false in the initialization list and set true when ready to be called.

Comment: if a derived class passes this into it, which is also problematic, the callback could still happen between the derived class's destructor and autoregister's destructor. Which I think is a race condition in your autoregister. How would this be used in derived?

Comment: You originally used raw pointers so I used raw pointers. The assumption is that any 'callback' object must outlive the autoregister object that keeps a callback pointer. If elsewhere in your code you don't have such a guarantee, one way to do so is to change 'callback*const callback_' inside autoregister with 'shared_ptr<callback> callback_'.

Comment: do I derive from autoregister, callback or both? How do I used this?

Comment: @Martin: You derive a class from `callback`, then create an `autoregister` instance, and pass the address of your `callback`-derivative when you create it. That will register the callback when it's created, and de-register it when it's destroyed.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry Coffin. That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

You should separate callback and registration handle. Nobody beside callback_manager needs `call_me` method, so why keep it visible from outside? Use `std::function` as a callback because it is very convenient: any callable can be converted to it and lambdas are very handy. Return a `Handle` object from callback registration method. The only method Handle will have would be a destructor from which you will remove the callback.

```
class Handle {
public:
    explicit Handle(std::function<void()> deleter)
        : deleter_(std::move(deleter))
    {}

    ~Handle()
    {
        deleter_();
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> deleter_;
};

class Manager {
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> Callback;

    Handle subscribe(Callback callback) {
        // NOTE: use mutex here if this method is accessed from multiple threads
        callbacks_.push_back(std::move(callback));
        auto itr = callbacks_.end() - 1;
        // NOTE If Handle lifetime can exceed Manager lifetime, store handlers_ in std::shared_ptr and capture a std::weak_ptr in lambda.
        return Handle([this, itr]{
            // NOTE: use mutex here if this method is accessed from multiple threads
            callbacks_.erase(itr);
        });
    }

private:
    std::list<Callback> callbacks_;
};
```

> Q1: are there other race conditions?

Callback/Handle may outlive `callback_manager` and will try to unsubscribe itself from deleted object. This can be fixed either by policy (always unsubscribe everything before deleting manager) or by using weak pointers.

And there is an obvious race if `callback_manager` is accessed from multiple threads you need to guard callbacks storage with mutexes.

> Q2: how to do this right (without race conditions, undefined behavior
>   and other errors) without asking the derived class to call register
>   manually?

See above.

> Q3: how to check if a virtual function can be called on a pointer?

This is not possible.

Comment: doesn't seem to answer my question, and seems to add more chances for race conditions, then again, maybe I don't understand what you mean

Comment: No it's not. But writing a code sample takes time. Wait a bit.

Comment: can you please add an example of code for the derived class also? .. also, by the way, does the iterator survive modifications to the list?

Comment: There is no derived class in my example and that's very convinient. Use lambdas: `auto handle = manager.subscribe([/* capture needed variables here */]{ /* Write your callback code here */})`. `std::list` is used exactly because it's iterators are not invalidated on modifications.

Comment: I know lambdas are great, but I'll pass on them in this case due to excessive overhead (e.g. millions of objects), otherwise the solution is what I was hoping to avoid by automating the registration by deriving from a class, mainly to reduce lines of code, each having a nonzero probability of errors. It seems that my original idea is impossible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can get rid of lambda in Handle and store pointer and iterator there. You can use functor with virtual `operator()` instead of std::function as a callback. And this API is quite fool proof. It is hard to misuse it.

Answer (score 1):

A race condition is when two threads are trying to do something at the same time, and the outcome depends on the precise timing. I don't think there is a race condition in this snippet because `this` is only accessible to the thread executing the constructor. There may however be a race condition in `callback_manager`, but you haven't posted the code for that so I can't tell.

There is another issue here: Objects are constructed from the base to the most derived, so at the time `autoregister`'s constructor is running, the virtual `call_me` cannot be called. See [this FAQ entry](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#calling-virtuals-from-ctors). There is no way to check if a virtual function call will work apart from ensuring the class is fully constructed.

Any solution to this problem that works by inheritance can't ensure that the class being registered is fully constructed before the callback is registered, so the registration must be done externally to the class being registered. The best you can do is have some RAII wrapper which registers the object on construction and deregisters it on destruction, and perhaps force the objects to be created through a factory that handles registration.

Comment: callback_manager could be race free, still it could call a callback on an object which isn't constructed, or half destroyed, that's what I meant by race condition, since it's rare to happen normally.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Donghui Zhang is on the right track, *but* still not really quite there yet, so to speak. Unfortunately, what he's done introduces its own set of pitfalls--for example, if you pass the address of a local object to `autoregister`'s ctor, you can still register a callback object that immediately goes out of scope (but doesn't necessarily immediately get deregistered).

I also think it's questionable (at best) to define a callback interface using `call_me` as the member function to invoke when calling back. If you need to define a type that can be invoked like a function, C++ already defines a name for that function: `operator()`. I'm going to enforce that instead of `call_me` being present.

To do all this, I think you really want to use a template instead of inheritance:

```
template <class T>
class autoregister {
    T t;
public:
    template <class...Args>
    autoregister(Args && ... args) : t(std::forward(args)...) {
       static_assert(std::is_callable<T>::value, "Error: callback must be callable");

       callback_manager.register(t);
    }

    ~autoregister() { callback_manager.deregister(t); }
};
```

You'd use this something like this:

```
class f {
public:
     virtual void operator()() { /* ... */ }
};

autoregister<f> a;
```

The `static_assert` assures that the type you pass as the template parameter can be called like a function.

This also supports passing arguments through `autoregister` to the constructor for the object it contains, so you might have something like:

```
class F {
public:
    F(int a, int b) { ... }
    void operator()() {}
};

autoregister<F> f(1,2);
```

...and the `1, 2` will be passed through from `autoregister` to `F` when it's constructed. Also note that this doesn't attempt to enforce a specific signature for the callback function. If you were, for example, to modify your callback manager to do the callback as `int r = callback(1);`, then the code would only compile if the callback objects you registered could be invoked with an `int` argument, and returned an `int` (or something that could be implicitly converted to an `int`, anyway). The compiler will enforce the callback having a signature compatible with how it's called. The only big shortcoming here is that if you pass a type that can be called, but (for example) can't be called with the parameter(s) that the callback manager tries to pass, the error message(s) you get may not be as readable as you'd like.

Comment: does what I want, but now I have to remember to use autoregister<derived> instead of derived, I could use a typedef, then if I want a second callback it will be register_boom<register_bang<derived>> maybe it's just me, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Martin:  In one case when you define your type you have to remember to derive from an `autoregister` class. In the other, you template over the `autoregister` class. I don't see a significant difference. Not sure I understand what you're talking about with a "second callback". If you mean multiple callback managers, it seems like you're broadening the question to something not even contemplated in the question, nor supported well by its design. If you actually care about that it's fairly easy to accommodate though.

Comment: the class is declared once, which is where you inherit, and change inheritance, possibly a single line, but your solution requires modification and remembering the registration for each instantiation, and nothing prevents the code from instantiating derived next to autoregister<derived>, which may be undesired and is enforced by inheritance. The user of the class shouldn't have to do this, the class should enforce its own policy. after all the class needs the callback, not the user of the class.

Comment: And the other point, yes it seems I'm broadening the question, but I'm not, not really. If the solution is limited to a single callback, it's so limited it could be called crippled, sorry, really not want to pick a fight, but it's like a file system which allows a single file to exist, or some other example. The point of good code is to allow composability, or at least I think so, personally, I don't like such a limitation. again, sorry to disagree, but I do

Comment: besides, your solution does not really depend on the use of the call operator.

Comment: @Martin: If you can show exactly what sort of composability you actually want, I'm pretty sure it can be accommodated. Right now, it looks to me like the example you give in the question is no more composable than what I've shown. I, at least, don't see a fight here. If you have requirements that weren't originally clear, you're entirely free to clarify what your real requirements are. At least to me, however, it's not yet clear what you *really* want. "Composability" is a nice principle, but at least so far you haven't shown what you want to compose, or how.

Comment: My point is that my version doesn't preclude another similar class, yours does since they would clash on the operator.

Comment: @Martin: It's certainly true that if (for example) you want your class to contain two different callback functions to be registered with two different callback managers, then you'd have to change what I've posted--but also that you'd have to change what you posted. I'd note, however, that having two different callback functions in a class starts to sound (a lot) like this isn't mere "composability", but much more likely than not a violation of the single responsibility principle, raising substantial question about the design.

Comment: That's not to say that the design is *necessarily* terrible--but it does mean it probably deserves some thought. In legal terms, it's not enough to support a conviction, but more than enough to support an indictment.

Comment: mine would not have to be changed as far as the original functionality is concerned, adding a new callback doesn't change the original callback stuff at all, a new class, register_othervent, and add it to the inheritance, no other changes, no changes unrelated to the "other" event. ..... I can have a single responsibility, with multiple events, e.g. shutdown, not_enough_widgets..... and the biggest problem is requiring the users of my class to know I am interested in mouse_moved_out_of_window, and relying on them doing it right and not being able to prevent them.

Comment: You consider "add it to the inheritance" a minor change? Changing to multiple inheritance is major enough that many languages prohibit it completely. Regardless of that, however, 1) yes, if you really want to invoke two separate named functions, this basic design is fine with that (the only change needed is to remove the `static_assert`). 2) I'd started with the assumption that you had at least some clue of the basics of C++. if you want the user of the class to see the name `bar` instead of using `autoregister<foo>`, you write `class foo {...}; typedef autoregister<foo> bar;`.

Comment: It's minor enough, the user of my class need not know what I do or why, just what I promise and how to use it. But I said that already, you don't need to agree with me, or listen to me. None of this addresses my original question and since you're dragging my skill level into it it's a waste of time as well. Thanks for your answer, it's clever, but doesn't fit my needs.